# 5G Wifi Network not working when connecting my monitor via HDM

Tags: networking, multiple-monitors, internet, hdmi

I am using a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 on it. My wireless router has both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz networks.

When I connect to the 2.4Ghz network, while also using an external monitor via a HDMI cable, everything works great.

When I connect to the 5Ghz network while also using an external monitor via a HDMI cable, the speed slows down dramatically or the connection just drops and I can't find the network any more in the Wifi Network dialog.

When I connect to the 5Ghz network, without being connected to the external monitor via HDMI, everything works great, the network has good speed, etc.

I would also like to mention that in both the case with the external monitor and without the external monitor, the lid of the laptop remains opened.

I have scoured the internet for answers but at this point I really don't know what to do. Any help debugging and fixing this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. You are making an assumption on the value of my monitor. How do you know it was cheap? :) (It was not)

Comment: 2. It is stated in the question quite clearly I am using a Wifi network. What wlan cable?

Comment: 3. You could have not answered the question if you did not intend to give may helpful advice. :)

Comment: Some electrical devices do harm wireless communications (either by design or by error). Maybe your monitor is trash or has a serious problem. Please move your monitor to your wireless access point, connect it to your computer and check if other wireless devices on 5GHz frequency are also disturbed. Maybe the HDMI cable is trash, because it has no shield or so, or the shield is broken. So try to test with another HDMI cable, please use no trash cable. :-) PS the term "wlan cable" was an IT joke